# Is an X-shaped Pipe a Double Torus?

Tags: general-topology

According to answers in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675390/19341), a X-shaped pipe should have a Euler characteristic of -2.
Looking up to examples at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Examples), we find that the Double torus also has an Euler characteristic of -2.

$\hskip0.1in$[image][image]

Can both things be transformed into each other without cutting? I don't see how...

Comment: This depends on how you think about the pipe as a surface. If you think of the metal as being infinitely thin and being the surface itself, then it has an edge (consisting of four circles). If you think of the metal as the "filling", and the surface of the metal as the surface (the way a simple metal pipe becomes a torus), then I think the genus is too large (and as a consequence, the Euler characteristic too small). Not too certain on that, though, which is why this is a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Compact surfaces with boundary are [classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Surfaces_with_boundary) by their Euler characteristic, orientability and number of boundary components. As the X-tube has 4 boundary components, and the 2-torus has 0 boundary components, they cannot be homotopy equivalent (and hence cannot be homeomorphic). You need all three characteristics to coincide in order to be homotopy equivalent.

Comment: +1 thanks...$ $

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of an X-shaped pipe. Take, for example, a regular cylindrical pipe. You can define it to be a cylinder, or you can define it to be a torus (which, of course, can be deformed to look just like a regular cylindrical pipe).

If you define an X-shaped pipe by gluing together the boundaries of four cylinders, then Dan Rust's answer has got you covered.

However, you might think of an X-shaped pipe as a sphere whose surface has four tunnel entrances, with all tunnels connecting inside the sphere (that is, a sphere with an X-shaped hole). This can be deformed to look just like an X-shaped pipe. In this case, the X-shaped pipe is actually ambient isotopic to a triple torus (like a torus, but with three holes).

To see this, try to imagine what happens when you drastically widen one of the tunnel entrances.

Hope this helps after nine months!

Comment: +1 it does, thank you!